# Use ${ServerlessHttpApi} in AWS SecretManager SecretString

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

How to populate the Secret Manager Notification Url with the API URL?
The code below throws a circular reference.
I have tried multiple !Sub but nothing seems to work

```
Resources:  
  SquareWebhookAuthorizerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: square-webhook-authorizer/
      Handler: app.SquareWebhookAuthorizerFunction
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SignatureKey: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${SquareSecret}:SecretString:SignatureKey}}'
          NotificationUrl: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${SquareSecret}:SecretString:NotificationUrl}}'
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref SquareWebhookEventTable
      Events:
        SquareWebhookEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: POST

  SquareSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: SquareSecretProxy
      Description: "Square App Secrets"
      SecretString: !Sub |
        '{
          "SignatureKey": "xxxx",
          "NotificationUrl": https://${ServerlessHttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/",
        }'
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the NotificationUrl in secrets manager? If you put it somewhere else, you won't have the circular reference. The lambda depends on the api and the secret, which depends on the api.

Comment: The url is part of the signature input parameters for square. I was able to remove the URL out of the ssm and use event['headers']['host']  directly in the lambda instead